# SFTP issue SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sftp

While using FTP wizard in SSIS getting error "Server name credentials,port may be invalid". However I am using same credentials ,server name and port on Winscp it's working.
* I am using Port : 22 (SFTP)
Please suggest what to do?
Thank you !

Comment: FTP and SFTP are not the same. You can't use FTP to connect to an SFTP server. SSIS does not support SFTP natively, so you will need to use a custom script/task/command line execution/etc to use SFTP.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any sample for this one that you may share with me ! that will be very helpful !!!

Comment: Personally, I use [PSFTP](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html), and then call the executable using an Execute Process Task, passing the necessary parameters/switches.

Comment: Since you already are using WinSCP, you could just follow their tutorial for using it in an SSIS Script Task: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis